# Apache-Flink Quickstart - reading CSV file error : Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]

Tags: java, csv, exception, apache-flink

I want to read CSV file using Flink-API locally, by the following code:

```
csvPath="data/weather.csv";
List<Tuple2<String, Double>> csv= env.readCsvFile(csvPath)
                                 .types(String.class,Double.class).collect();
```

I tried some files in different size(from 800mb to 6gb). Sometimes the operation is completed successfully and sometimes it is not, because of the following timeout exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:153)
at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:169)
at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:169)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
at scala.concurrent.Await$.ready(package.scala:169)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.shutdown(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:439)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.stop(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:408)
at org.apache.flink.client.LocalExecutor.stop(LocalExecutor.java:127)
at org.apache.flink.client.LocalExecutor.executePlan(LocalExecutor.java:195)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.LocalEnvironment.execute(LocalEnvironment.java:91)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:923)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:410)
at org.apache.flink.simpleCSV.run(simpleCSV.java:83)
```

how can I fix this problem? increase this timeout programmatically? Or should I put a config file somewhere? Is there a specific heap size that I should set based on the file size?

Answer (score 2):

`collect()` transfers the data from the cluster to the local client. This does only work for very small data sets (< 10 MB).

If you have larger data sets, you need to process them on the cluster and emit the results through an output format, e.g., write it to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to increase this timeout programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging this program, you can set a break point at the constructor of org.apache.flink.api.java.LocalEnvironment (the constructor with config) and run the following command to change the timeout to 200 seconds (Alt+F8 in IntelliJ Idea):

```
config.setString("akka.ask.timeout", "200 s")
```

To find LocalEnvironment class in IntelliJ Idea, press Ctr+n, and check "Include non-project classes in the pop-up window, then type "LocalEnvironment" in the edit box.